# Why isn't the SVG element working on ios devices?

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone, svg

I have the following `<h1>` tag that has a design (Svg) that works on screens that have a minimum width of 800px. Now, when I write a media query for devices with a minimum width of 400px (Mobile phones), the SVG element does not come at all.

**HTML**

```
<div class="explanation">
                  <h1>
                     <div class="goo" contenteditable="true">Elected as a <i>Senior Project Lead</i> <br>at the Biggest Club<br> involved in Technology and Coding: <span id = 'newline'>Coffee</span> 'N' Code.</div>
                  </h1>
                  <!-- Filter: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/ -->
                  <svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
                     <defs>
                        <filter id="goo">
                           <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
                           <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
                           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
                        </filter>
                     </defs>
                  </svg>
               </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.goo {
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
  display: inline;
  box-decoration-break: clone;
  background: var(--color-highlight);
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  filter: url('#goo');
  color: black;
}

.goo:focus {
  outline: 0;
}
```

How it is seen on screens with a large width:

[image]

How it appears on my ios device:

[image]

Although the layout is different, which is as required, why aren't the edges rounded? And why isn't there a break in the SVG element as well as is there in the first picture? Am I missing something here?

Comment: Question: Why are you using an SVG for this? Why not just a regular `<div>`?

Comment: Otherwise how will the effect be possible? Do you have another solution to this then? In other words, are you asking me to reformat the entire HTML code?

Comment: No, I just think that if you are having trouble with the SVGs, then you should try something else or seek for more help.

Chill dude, don't worry about having to refactor your code. That's part of the process. 

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete - why are all line starts but the first moved to the left? Therefor, no answer, but only a few tips to try: 1. Expand the [filter region](http://apike.ca/prog_svg_filtering.html#filter-area), for example with `<filter id="goo" x="-50%" y="-50%" width="200%" height="200%">`. 2. make sure your `<h1>` element has the default `everflow: visible` property.

Comment: Did not work. Not sure why you said the code was incomplete. I guess it was poorly formatted and I apologize for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using purely html/css. One advise is you should only use SVG for images,text animations, gif images.

Here's the code:

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="explanation">
<p class="description">
<span>Elected as a Senior Project Lead</span>
</p>
<p class="description">
<span>at the Biggest Club</span>
</p>
<p class="description">
<span>involved in Technology and Coding: Coffee 'N' Code.</span>
</p>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.explanation {
  padding:1rem;
  background:#000;
}

.explanation .description {
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  margin:0;
}

.explanation .description span {
  display:inline-block;
  background:#fff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size:2rem;
  line-height: 1.35;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .explanation .description span {
     font-size:1.2rem;
   }
}
```

You should use media query to have any adjustments in CSS in responsive mode by using this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
}
```

just adjust the pixels where you would like to change the styling. Or you can play with the media queries.

Comment: I don't think the effect is replicated. I used the code you have given and it does not produce the same effect. I wanted the font to be black in colour with a white wavy background only for the letters.